# Query runs for hours

Tags: sql-server, timeout, linked-server

Some of the queries that execute overnight run for exactly 5 hours before logging a failure message. These queries retrieve records from a linked server which is also a SQL server. When I run the same query in the morning it executes in a minute. The timeout property in both servers is set to 1 hour. So I'm trying to understand how it can execute for more than an hour and how it can stop after 5 hours every time. Please help me understand what I'm missing.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your select @@version?

Comment: Under what account  "queries that execute overnigh" are executed? Are they scheduled and executed by Agent?

Comment: version - SQL Server 2014 SP1. The queries are placed in a procedure which is run using a scheduled SQL Server Agent job.

Comment: Ok for version, but under what user this job is executed? Did you try to exec the sp under the same account in the morning?

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible for that particular query which runs on that particular session/ window, if you are using transaction methodology in your queries, transaction had not been in committed state so it should be rollback before executing again.

Reason 2 - Linked server functionality had not been working at that time when you were executed the query.

Comment: 1. Transaction is not used. 2. If the link server was not available, it would have thrown an exception.